# Search with condition doesn't work in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The items in the collection look like this:

```js
{
  settings: {
    starboard: {
      channelID: '1129422168984387594',
      reqReacts: 1,
      data: [Map],
      customReact: '⭐'
    },
    neuro: { search: 'Allow' }
  },
  _id: new ObjectId("649e9d53188b7e7bb4f02cef"),
  __v: 0,
}
```

'settings.neuro.search' is not set to 'All' for only 1 element of the collection (its example above).

I enter the following code:

```js
Collection.find({ 'settings.neuro.search': {$ne : 'All'}}).then(function(results) {
console.log(results)
})
```

All items in the collection are sent to the console, even those with `settings.neuro.search` set to `All`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: probably an issue with the mongoose schema definition. Can you show it?

Comment: if "settings" is not in the schema definition, then mongoose won't send that part of the filter to mongodb, and it gives you everything.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey https://imgur.com/a/Ir2YxDY Here is my schema

Comment: looks good to me. Maybe show more code so we can see if everything else is correct